# 400 when getting OAuth2 Scalatest in Play framework

Tags: scala, playframework, oauth-2.0, token, scalatest

I am trying to get OAuth2 bearer token in play framework scalatest.
However, the server seems cant understand the json I am sending in the FakeRequest().
The fakerequest is like this

```
val req = FakeRequest().withBody(
Json.obj(
"grant_type" -> "client_credentials",
"client_credentials" -> clientID,
"client_secret" -> clientSecret,
"scope" -> "all"
))
```

it says that

> {"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"required parameter:
>   grant_type"}

Do you have any idea why it is not working?
it works perfectly fine in swagger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try specifying the request method as POST in the FakeRequest object. FakeRequest maybe doing a GET by default, hence it is unable to find the request parameters.